# Is there any software to keep eyes distracted from monitor

Tags: display, user-interface, resolution, display-settings, user-experience

I have a 19 inch LCD monitor but my eyes are hurting when sitting too much in front of the PC so I used an eye protector software, but it irritates me since it is a trial version, so I cannot edit its settings, so it just pops up accordingly to its predefined time.

Can any one suggest me a good software. This is the site of that software http://www.eyeprotectorpro.com/

Comment: You need a software to remind you to look away from the machine every so often?  How about you just...look away from the machine every so often?!

Comment: Alternatively you can lower the brightness of your monitor, and perhaps move it a bit farther away from you.

Comment: Physically getting up to walk around and stretch once in a while (e.g., every hour) is highly recommended by many medical, physiotherapy, and fitness professionals too.

Comment: This isn't software but a window works great for me. Whenever my eyes start to get sore, I look out the window at some trees/grass/sky or other blue-green objects. I don't need  a timer because I can feel when I've been staring at a screen for too long. Likewise, I can feel when my body is uncomfortable from sitting too long, so I'll stand up and stretch or do some exercises. In fact, I can't imagine not doing these things. It's like forgetting to eat. Your body sends you signals to let you know you need a break.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

workrave is an RSI (repetative strain injury) app that interrupts you periodically to rest your eyes, hands, and stretch. The timers are configurable for your needs, and it supports networking (in the event that you use multiple computers). I Highly recommend it.

http://www.workrave.org/

Workrave is free.

EDIT: Available for Windows/Linux

[image: workrave screen shot]

Comment: I used Workraave for a while a few years ago and contrary to my assumption, I really did take the breaks and rarely skipped or postponed them… at least for quite a while. I hope to use it again soon, but I just don’t have the time to take breaks. `:-(`

Comment: @Synetech: I use this to do pretty much the opposite.  http://www.focusboosterapp.com/

Answer (score 3):

I know how irritating it can be to have your eyes strained by a monitor. Whenever I've had to change jobs/offices I noticed my eyes would start to hurt within a few hours of sitting at the PC. Adjusting both the brightness and contrast always solved that problem.

A little while ago, the lighting above the area where I work dimmed for whatever reason, and I noticed my eyes began to hurt once more. This proved to me that its not just the monitor display settings, which had not changed, but the lighting of the rest of the environment that made the difference. Again, even in this case, adjusting both the brightness and contrast on the PC display relieved the strain on my eyes.

**Edit** (@FrozenKing replying to your comment below)

### **Current Display Settings**

**desktop**

Standard lighting: Brightness 60, contrast 65

Low lighting: Brightness 65, contrast 55

CURRENT: Brightness 50, contrast 50

**laptop**

low (current) lighting: Brightness 45, contrast 35

Really Low lighting: Brightness 0, contrast 0

---

If I were to forget what they were or they were reset by accident, I would do:

1. check for sense of subtle strain on the eyes while sitting in front of PC
2. adjust brightness or contrast down until I got a noticeable improvement in eye strain
3. if I don't like the screen display color quality, increase either one of brightness/contrast while ensuring my eyes are not affected.
4. keep going back to #1 until I feel no strain on my eyes at all

I think the key is that my eyes are sensitive enough that I don't need to sit in front of a PC for hours before knowing whether the settings are right for me or not. I know immediately. On the other hand, it might be much harder to find the right settings after my eyes have been straining for a very long time.

Comment: Waht values you put in contrast and brightness. I am using 51 value for brightness and 50 for contrast.

Comment: @FrozenKing, see edited reply

Comment: @FrozenKing: unless you have the same model displays as drapkin11, his results from those settings are unlikely to correspond to the output from your monitor. You might have better luck if you guys were calibrating your displays from synchronized ICC profiles, but even then different monitors have different contrast ratios and brightness ranges.

Answer (score 2):

All you want is to **protect your eyes from the computer screen**. Thus, try these tips as below:

**Monitor Location**
Ideally more than 25 inches from eye and 6 inches below the horizontal eye level.
Anti-glare screen
Will decrease the amount of light reflected from the screen.

**Light effect**
Use suspended lights from ceiling and windows with shades, blinds or curtains. Avoid light hitting directly on eyes.

**Sitting posture**
Use chairs with armrests which are able to provide, support while typing, position of head slightly tilted downwards and height of the chair adjusted appropriately so that the feet reset flat on floor.

**20-20-20 rule**
Follow the 20-20-20 rule, which means every 20 minutes, look away from the monitor, and focus on an object at least 20 feet away, for 20 seconds.

**Eye Exercise**
Choose your eyes and slowly roll your eyeballs clockwise and anticlockwise. Repeat it 3 times.

**Blinking**
Blink frequently to keep the front surface of your eye moist.

**Computer Eyewear**
To block the blue light, glare, and radiation when in computer and mobile device use. It works better than a monitor or screen protector.

Answer (score 1):

Great, free software for eye relax is [Eyes Relax](http://themech.net/eyesrelax/).

[image]
<sup>image by [themech.net](http://themech.net/eyesrelax/)</sup>